# how to delete data from data grid view using ms access in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer, ms-access-2003

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //i have used this query for delete button
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
    OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter();  
    OleDbConnection con = new 
    OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
    Source=C:\Users\HP\Desktop\sd.mdb");
    con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
    Source=C:\Users\HP\Desktop\sd.mdb";
    con.Open();
    //this is the query i have used
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM car_model WHERE Description ='" + des+ "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted");
    con.Close();
}
//i have table named:car_model & attribute as Description
```

Comment: You wrote what you did, but didn't write what's the issue? What happens, and what you expect to happen?

Comment: have a issue to delete data

Comment: i have selected a row to delete then press a button but it could'nt deleted its may show the message box box but not remove that item from grid view and access

Comment: What is +des+ you need to define that or tell database where to get that,if data in database is des,use ='des'. Also try using parameters.

Comment: "des" is the name of text box..

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  If `des` is a TextBox, then you would have to use `des.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes don't look right, but my eyes are not great and anyway, the compiler would pick that up immediately, so I guess it's something else.

```
private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dataGridView1.SelectedItem;
   int id = drv.Row[0];
   if(drv != null)
   {
       delete(id);
   }
}

public void delete(int id)
{ 
   try 
   {
      con.Open();
      OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("Delete From Car_Model Where Description = @Des", con);
      comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", id);
      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   catch(OleDbException ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("DataConnection not found!", ex);
   }
   finally
   {
       con.Close();
   }
```

Also, use the '@' character to prevent SQL Injection issues.  I don't think this is necessarily a problem with MS Access, but it's a good habit to get into.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp